# errors exporting audio over ssh

Tags: ssh, audio, vlc-media-player

i am attempting to forward audio (x11 video is already working) over my local lan from a source pc to a client pc. both machines are running ubuntu. i have followed [these instructions](http://myubu.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/secure-shell-ssh-to-another-computer-with-audio-and-video-forwarding/) but i'm getting some errors.

here is the result of the `pax11publish` command on each workstation:

```
[me@source ~] $ pax11publish
Server: {fb...05}unix:/home/me/.pulse/fb...05-runtime/native tcp:client-pc:4713 tcp6:client-pc:4713
Cookie: ac22 ... d0

[me@client ~] $ pax11publish
Server: {fb...05}unix:/home/me/.pulse/fb...05-runtime/native tcp:client-pc:4713 tcp6:client-pc:4713
Cookie: ac22...d0
```

to get these settings to work i configured `paprefs` the same on both the client and the source by ticking the following boxes:

```
network access tab > make discoverable pulseaudio network sound devices available locally
network server tab > enable network access to local sound devices
network server tab > allow other machines on the lan to discover local sound devices
simultaneous output tab > add virtual output device for simultaneous output on all local sound cards
```

i proceeded to `ssh` from the client pc to the source pc:

```
$ ssh -C -R 24713:localhost:4713 user@source_pc -X
```

and then on the source pc:

```
$ export PULSE_SERVER="tcp:localhost:24713"
```

note that i typed `localhost` literally here - didn't change it to the pc's name. should i have?

anyway... when i attempted to send audio from the remote server by starting up vlc, it gave the following errors:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 1.0.6 Goldeneye
[0x10dd888] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x15f6918] pulse audio output: No. of Audio Channels: 2
[0x15f6918] pulse audio output error: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4154:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4154:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4154:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4633:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2211:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[0x15f6918] oss audio output error: cannot open audio device (/dev/dsp)
```

help!

**update**

when i issue a beep at the source terminal:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

i do hear the beep, so maybe its just a problem with the vlc player config?

Comment: to check if port 4713 is open and which process is listening to it, use `netstat -lnp | grep 4713`

Comment: @guido thanks. the output from that command on the client end is completely blank. any more ideas?

Comment: it means the process is not running on that machine, or it does but using a different port. first identify if the process is running (`ps ax | grep ....`), take note of the pid, then run again `netstat -lnp | grep thepidyounoted` ). This will tell you the port

Comment: i changed some `paprefs` settings and now the port is showing up. i will update the question so you can see the output of this command. the same error is still coming up when i try and play across the network though.